# How can I move multiple objects with Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, touch-event

Here is my code

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *myTouch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    UITouch *myTouch2 = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    UITouch *myTouch3 = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    button.center = [myTouch locationInView:self.view];
    button2.center = [myTouch2 locationInView:self.view];
    button3.center = [myTouch3 locationInView:self.view];   
}
```

The problem is, when I try to move one of the buttons, they all move at the same time and same position. I want to be able to move buttons separately and freely. How do I do that? Any suggestions?

Comment: Your approach is unnecessarily low level.  You should find an example of how to move a `UIView` by using a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` (there are many—on the Internet and on StackOverflow) and instead simply apply a gesture recognizer to each `UIButton`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following to determine which button it is:

```
UITouch *touch = [[event touchesForView:self.view] anyObject];

CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];

if(CGRectContainsPoint(button.frame, location)) 
{
    button.center = [myTouch locationInView:self.view];

}
else if(CGRectContainsPoint(button2.frame, location)) 
{
    button2.center = [myTouch locationInView:self.view];

}
else if(CGRectContainsPoint(button3.frame, location)) 
{
    button3.center = [myTouch locationInView:self.view];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to be able to move buttons separately and freely.

Then you shouldn't move them all to the same place at the same time:

```
UITouch *myTouch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
UITouch *myTouch2 = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
UITouch *myTouch3 = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
```

Take a look at `myTouch`, `myTouch2`, and `myTouch3` -- they may all point to the very same touch object. And in that case, you'll be moving all your buttons to the same location.

If you're expecting multiple touches, you'll need to look at the set of touches in `[event allTouches]` and make sure that you're getting distinct objects for each button. You could for example pick the touch object that's closest to each button, making sure that you don't use the same touch for two buttons.